# How can I add http access to an existing svn repository without disabling svn+ssh access?

Tags: ssh, svn, http

I am attempting to add read-only HTTP access to an existing `svn` repository while still allowing write access via `svn+ssh`.

I have installed Apache, mod_dav_svn, etc. and pointed Apache at the `svn` repository, but when I attempt to access the repo via HTTP, I get the following error:

```
Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
```

When I look at the error_log for Apache, I see that it can't open the `format` file in my repository. That file is readable by everyone but writable by no one, and it seems to work for `svn+ssh` access. How can I resolve the problem for Apache without impacting `svn+ssh` access for the developers?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**: It appears this isn't restricted to the existing repo. I just created a brand-new test repo, ran `chown -R apache:apache` on it, and I still get the same problem. I've verified that the `apache` user *does* have execute permissions on every directory on the way to `format` and read permissions on `format`. However, if I create a test repo somewhere in the directory tree Apache is using as the document root, things work OK. Is Apache `chroot`ed (or similar) on CentOS 5.3? If so, can I circumvent that? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an SELinux issue... do you have denials in /var/log/audit/audit.log ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can accomplish this by creating an *svn* group and placing all your users as well as the apache (or www-run, or whatever the user that apache runs under) user in to the group. Then you can change the permissions of the repository so that it is owned by the *svn* group.

That being said, I think the preferred route would be to move everything over to WebDAV. The reason here being that in order for svn+ssh to work, users need to have direct write access to the repository, as well as SSH access to the server. This provides a lot of potential for damage to the repository, as well as other potential security risks.

With WebDAV, the users are restricted to only performing operations through the WebDAV server. There are many advantages to this approach including, but not limited to, fine-grained access control, more authentication options, auditing, etc.

Comment: Apache is already a member of my svnusers group, which owns the repository, as are the developers who can successfully use the repo via svn+ssh. The format file is chmoded 444.